# On select change update the nearest input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code:
https://jsfiddle.net/wjkh6hb7/1/

When I change the select option it should update the nearest input, but actually it doesn't.

I think it's because of the select name `RAT_Rates[]` because I need to get the result as an array.

Anyone can explain me how I can change this ?

Here the JS code:

```
$("select[name='RAT_Rates[]']").on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

    var name = selected.attr('data-name');
    var description = selected.attr('data-description');
    var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');

    if(rate!='') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Rate[]']").val(rate).prop('readonly', true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Rate[]']").val('').prop('readonly', false);
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the selector doesn't exist.

```
var s = $( "select[name='RAT_Rates[]']" ).length;
console.log( s ); // 0
```

Try using the selector for the dropdown:

```
$( "select[name='BIL_RateId[]']" )
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eg4eLcL1/

Comment: or for better readability add common classes to similar elements

Answer (score 0):

Reasons behind its not working that-

1.you call a non exist selector `select[name='RAT_Rates[]']`.
2.select name same for both .it should distinct for both name attributes good practise.like `BIL_RateId`,`"BIL_Rate[]` and `BIL_RateId1`,`"BIL_Rate1[]`

working example Fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjkh6hb7/2/)

Html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Date</th>
            <th width="40%">Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Today<br>
                <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Tarif personnalisé</option>
                    <option value="3" data-name="Spécial étudiant" data-description="Spécial étudiant" data-rate="99.99">Spécial étudiant - $ 99.99</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tomorrow<br>
                <select name="BIL_RateId1[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" data-name="" data-description="" data-rate="" selected="">Tarif personnalisé</option>
                    <option value="3" data-name="Spécial étudiant" data-description="Spécial étudiant" data-rate="99.99">Spécial étudiant - $ 99.99</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate1[]" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("select[name='BIL_RateId1[]']").on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
console.log(selected);
    var name = selected.attr('data-name');
    var description = selected.attr('data-description');
    var rate = selected.attr('data-rate');

    if(rate!='') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Rate1[]']").val(rate).prop('readonly', true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Rate1[]']").val('').prop('readonly', false);
    }
});
```